# kill a looped task nicely from a jest test

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs

I have a worker method 'doSomeWork' that is called in a loop, based on a flag that will be changed if a signal to terminate is received.

```
let RUNNING = true;

let pid;

export function getPid() {
  return pid;
}

export async function doSomeWork() {
  console.log("Doing some work!");
}

export const run = async () => {
  console.log("starting run process with PID %s", process.pid);
  pid = process.pid;
  while (RUNNING) {
    await doSomeWork();
  }
  console.log("done");
};
run()
  .then(() => {
    console.log("finished");
  })
  .catch((e) => console.error("failed", e));

process.on("SIGTERM", () => {
  RUNNING = false;
});
```

I am happy with this and now need to write a test:  I want to

- trigger the loop
- inject a 'SIGTERM' to the src process
- give the loop a chance to finish nicely
- see 'finished' in the logs to know that the run method has been killed.

here is my attempt (not working)  The test code all executes, but the src loop isn't killed.

```
import * as main from "../src/program";

describe("main", () => {
  it("a test", () => {
    main.run();

    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log("5 seconds have passed - killing now!");
      const mainProcessPid = main.getPid();
      process.kill(mainProcessPid, "SIGTERM");
    }, 5000);

    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log("5 secs of tidy up time has passed");
    }, 5000);
  });
});
```

I think the setTimeout isn't blocking the test thread, but I am not sure how to achieve this in node/TS.

sandbox at https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-voice-goncm

update sandbox with correct environment: https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-bartik-ltjtx

any help appreciated :-)

--update---
I now see that process.kill isn't doing what I thought it was - even when I pass in the PID.  will try creating a process as a child of the test process, so I can send a signal to it then.  https://medium.com/@NorbertdeLangen/communicating-between-nodejs-processes-4e68be42b917

Comment: You can use abortcontroller kind of approach... Send an object reference as a parameter to your run method. Implement abort () method on that object inside your run method... (Simple process.kill).. from out side you can call abort method anytime you want

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I will play around with the obj ref in the run, but I really need to the process to be managed by the loop so that is completes the work in that method

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this issue because the Environment in your codesandbox is `create-react-app` i.e. it's a client side script and not a server-side instance of node.

Recreate you project but select as your environment `node HTTP server`, this will give you a node environment where the node `process` functions will work e.g. `process.kill`. This is because the node environment is run in a server-side Docker container. See [here](https://codesandbox.io/docs/environment) for more info on Codesandbox's environments.

Comment: thanks for that, I recreated the sandbox with the node http server env at https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-bartik-ltjtx however, I still see the issue, the test finishes without killing the main process.  this mirrors the behaviour I saw in the original env outside of a sandbox.

Comment: @tmc your sandbox is missing code for program.ts.

Comment: sorry. I may have been editing, I checked it there and froze it :-)